# Double cover of S3

Tags: group-theory

Some literature says that the symmetric group S3 has no nontrivial double cover,
as the Schur mulitplier is trivial.  But the Dicyclic group of order 12 seems like
a good double cover.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a matter of definition. The dicyclic group $G$ of order $12$ has centre $Z$ of order $2$ with $G/Z \cong S_3$, but $Z$ is not contained in the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ of $G$, so $G$ is not a "cover" of $S_3$ in the sense of Schur cover.